# PHP Writing long strings on separate lines

Tags: php

I wanted to write a line of code that contains a long string such as:

```
addError("This is a really really really really really really really long text");
```

however I wanted to split the text into multiple lines. How can this be possible **aside** from this way:

```
addError("This is a really really really really really really" .
       "really long text");
```

EDIT: I need it such that it dosen't do line breaks either. (forget about that SQL thing i said earlier)

Comment: If you want a line feed in the actual error text, use `"\n"` or `PHP_EOL`

Comment: There are a few ways. A [Heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) would possibly be your best bet, assuming your IDE doesn't get confused by them in the same way.

Comment: Then I'd suggest upgrading your IDE. While it's nice that it can detect "other languages" inside a PHP string and format them, if it can't handle perfectly valid php syntax, then that's the IDE's fault, not something you should have to work around.

Comment: Just out of interest, what IDE are you using?

Comment: @Mark Baker no I DONT want line breaks.

Comment: @Matt Gibson Dosen't this produce line breaks

Comment: You just want the string to show up in multiple lines in your code, but you don't want to concatenate needlessly?  Methinks you're stuck, and focusing more energy on this than it's worth.  Either just make it a really long line, or break it up into strings that you concatenate together.

Comment: @jason I think your right. Its just I thought there might be a way. At least now I know there isn't so i can continue to concatenate without thinking there is a better way in the back of my head.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If SQL syntax highlighting is your problem, you can probably format it properly using a heredoc, and still get the IDE's syntax highlighting working:

```
$query = <<<EOD
select *
from foo
where bar
EOD;

do_query($query);
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

If you don't want line breaks, your way of doing it now seems right. With the above, you'd need to remove the line breaks afterwards, e.g. `str_replace("\n", " ", $str)`.

Comment: This will produce line breaks. OP don't want line breaks (he told)

Comment: Oh, I see, OP edited the question. Then it's a +1 :)

Comment: @hek2mgl: I'm not seeing that in the question, yeah. I only see the reference to SQL syntax highlighting gone wrong when he breaks the query in multiple strings. Plus, OP really *should* format his SQL queries if possible, as it makes things a lot easier to read. :-)

Comment: Yeah I need it such that it dosen't have line breaks

Comment: Isn't it perfectly valid for SQL statements to have line breaks?

Comment: @MikeChristensen: Yeah, it is. And in fact, it's actually preferred, as it makes them a lot more readable when they're logged or when maintaining code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :-

```
$t = 'This is a really really really really really really';
$t .= ' really really really really really really';
$t .= ' really really really really really really';
$t .= ' long string';
addError( $t );
```

Comment: Yeah that produces the same problem. I don't want to use any concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are trying to break the output to rows, you can use [str_split( $string, $chunk_length )](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php).

This will split the long text into array of strings with a fixed length.

```
$array_of_strings = str_split($str, 100);//100 represents the length of the chunk
foreach ($array_of_strings as $line) {
  echo $line . '<br>';
}
```

You can also use [chunck_split();](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chunk-split.php)

Hope this helps!